# Are the windows clocks which are low resolution updated at thread context switches

Tags: windows, multithreading, timer

Several years ago I noticed that at the time the .Net DateTime class only changed in increments of about 10 - 15 milliseconds. That happens to coincide with what I understand is the typical duration of a thread context in windows (which is why threads never sleep for less than that). Are the low resolution windows clocks exposed there really updated precisely at thread context switches? Can they be used as a cheap and dirty way to detect context switches?

Comment: this is not really the right place to ask "how does it work" questions unless you have a specific problem you're trying to solve

Comment: No, because context-switches may not happen on every timer interrupt and happen often upon all the other hardware interrupts and API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, I'll go with an actual answer:

Are the low resolution windows clocks exposed there really updated precisely at thread context switches?

No - you've got it backwards.  The low-resolution Windows clock MAY precipitate a context-change, eg. if an API call with a timeout times out, or a Sleep() call expires.

Can they be used as a cheap and dirty way to detect context switches?

No, because context-switches may not happen on every timer interrupt and happen often upon all the other hardware interrupts and API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Where in the world did you learn such details?

Comment: @JohnRobertson - decades of writing multithreaded apps on servers, desktops and embedded.

Comment: @JohnRobertson  I want your job, when will you be done with it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You make several invalid or at least unwarranted assumptions.

First, you're assuming that the .NET limitation of 15 ms for updating `DateTime.Now` is a Windows limitation. It might be, but then it might not be.

You're assuming that the resolution of `Thread.Sleep()` is somehow related to `DateTime.Now`. It's not. You're also assuming that the minimum sleep of 15 ms is a Windows limitation. It isn't.

Also, the last part of this statement:

> That happens to coincide with what I understand is the typical duration of a thread context in windows (which is why threads never sleep for less than that).

Is completely false. A thread can give up the remainder of its timeslice, meaning that another thread can be scheduled to execute during that time. Threads *can* sleep for less than 15 ms, even in .NET programs.

More to the point, `DateTime.Now` and the mechanism used to do context switching are almost completely unrelated. It's possible that the value returned by `DateTime.Now` isn't even updated except when you ask for it, in much the same way as the `Stopwatch` class doesn't maintain an `Elapsed` field, but rather computes the elapsed time when you ask.

So, no, it's not possible to use the clock to detect context switches.

And, it turns out, that the myth of `DateTime.Now` resolution of 15 ms is false. This program demonstrates that:

```
        var results = new List<double>();
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        var endTime = startTime.AddSeconds(10);
        var lastTime = startTime;
        var nowTime = startTime;
        while (nowTime < endTime)
        {
            nowTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (nowTime != lastTime)
            {
                results.Add((nowTime - lastTime).TotalMilliseconds);
                lastTime = nowTime;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total changes = {0}", results.Count);
        var avg = results.Average();
        var min = results.Min();
        var max = results.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("Min: {0},  Max: {1},  Avg: {2}", min, max, avg);
```

That program checks `DateTime.Now` in a tight loop for 10 seconds, and adds an item to the list whenever the returned value changes. A typical run for me results in output very similar to:

```
Total changes = 9980
Min: 0.9999,  Max: 19.998,  Avg: 1.00210418837676
```

So it made 9,980 updates in 10,000 milliseconds. It looks to me as though there was only one time in which it *didn't* update each millisecond. That was probably because the thread was swapped out during that period.

Quite often I get:

```
Total changes = 10000
Min: 1,  Max: 1,  Avg: 1
```

Which means that the clock updated once per millisecond.

Comment: Haven't gone over this yet, but am glad to have unwarranted assumptions corrected. Thank you! Where did you learn these details?

I should clarify that a few years ago DateTime (or maybe it was stopwatch) really wouldn't return time changes of less than 10-15 ms. A similar test performed then would give a bunch of zeros. I had heard from some people that it might have been improved by now, which is appears to have been.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: I suppose I learned this just by working with it for so long. I recall running this test long ago and seeing similar results. To my recollection, I have never seen that 15 ms myth confirmed. A similar test with `Thread.Sleep(5)` in a loop will show you that a thread *will* sleep for less than 15 ms. *Timers*, on the other hand, do have that 15 ms limitation.